# Git exclude file does not seem to be excluding changed files

Tags: git, github, case-sensitive

I'm having a problem with excluding some binary files. I'm simply trying to get Git to ignore them through the 'exclude' file because I never work with them.  But I can't seem to get it to work.  Here is the background.  I'm working on Windows, but most of my team works on mac or Linux.  There are a couple of jpg files with the same name, but different case.  Ideally we should just change the names of the files, but I'm working on a fairly large team and this isn't as easy as you might think.

Since I never work with these files, I'm trying to locally exclude them from Git's view.  I first added the file names to the exclude file using both case versions (full paths copied directly from the messages I got from Git warning me of changed files that need to be committed before I checkout another branch).  Since this didn't work (I still get the same error messages and can't change branches) I tried simply adding *.jpg to the exclude file.  Still no luck.

I read that you need to remove the files from being tracked.  So I tried

```
git rm --cached filename
```

Once again using both case versions of the file.  But this shows the files as deleted in an uncommitted change.  If I commit these deletes, and then sync, won't this delete the files for everyone?

I also tried

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged filename
```

Once again, both filenames where used.  But that doesn't seem to have any effect.

I know from my research that this duplicate filename issue on Windows is a somewhat vexing problem and many of the usual git ways of dealing with it don't work.  But I would think that just telling git to exclude the files (or the whole file type as in this case) would work.  I even tried excluding the entire directory (dir1/dir2/images/*)  but that didn't work either. I just can't figure out why the exclude file doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: post your exclude file please!

Comment: I left the comments at the tope of the exclude file, but otherwise it is just:

*.jpg

Comment: So don't push the deletes, just push the new exclude file? ...that way nobody has to worry about deletes and people won't be pushing any more .jpgs = )!

Answer (score -1):

Don't push the deletes!

Push the new exclude file!

So nobody has to worry about deletes and people won't be pushing any more .jpgs = )!

And then figure out how to get rid of the jpgs from peoples machines if it matters!

Comment: I only want to exclude locally.  Other people work with the jpgs.  I thought the exclude was only for local excludes.  It doesn't show up as a changed file anywhere (presumably because it is only for local excludes)   So how could I push it anyway?  Am I missing something?

Comment: so just don't push the deletes? the .git/info/exclude file is local!

Comment: If I commit the deletes then make other changes, I would have to somehow back them out when I sync.  If I don't commit the deletes, it won't allow me to switch branches.  So it seems I'm sort of stuck.  I'm actually thinking of trying to commit the "changes" that Git perceives.  Then before pushing out, do a rollback and taking that particular file commit out.  And then re-committing all the other files and then push.  Seems like a lot of trouble.  It just seems there should be a way of having Git ignore the "changes" locally.